# xpath php - trouble with LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to find all p tags in a document, like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = '<p>First</p><p>Second</p><p>Third</p><h3>Test 2</h3><p>Fourth</p>';
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$itens = [];
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$res = $xp->query('//p');
foreach ($res as $item) {
    $itens[] = $item->nodeValue;
}

print_r($itens);
```

but when LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED is on, it doesn't work as expect. I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FirstSecondThirdTest 2Fourth
    [1] => Second
    [2] => Third
    [3] => Fourth
)
```

but I expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => First
    [1] => Second
    [2] => Third
    [3] => Fourth
)
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your HTML is actually a document fragment as it doesn't have a single root node.  `loadHTML()` tries to fix this and you can see if you do

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

you get

```
<p>First<p>Second</p><p>Third</p><h3>Test 2</h3><p>Fourth</p></p>
```

A simple fix is to add a base tag ( I use a `<div>`) to the source before loading...

```
$dom->loadHTML("<div>$html</div>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

which gives....

```
Array
(
    [0] => First
    [1] => Second
    [2] => Third
    [3] => Fourth
)
```

Comment: Is there any progress with this?